# django upload files proving more difficult than necessary

Tags: python, django, file-handling

I am trying to allow for files to be uploaded by users in on my django site. I started with the example command from the django documentation, input into views.py, independently of a form or model and just referred to in the template (and modified it so that multiple files can be uploaded at once,):

```
  def Upload(request):
    for count, x in enumerate(request.FILES.getlist("files")):# allows for multiple iterations/files
      def process():
         with open('/Users/Deirdre/bing/upload/media/file_', + str(count) 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
               destination.write(chunk)
       process(x)
     return HttpResponse("File(s) uploaded")
```

However on the "with open... as" the server keeps returning the errors "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" or "unexpected indentation"....
I know that neither of these are true so is there a way to bypass this difficulty? why is django not configuring with the commands???

Comment: Why are you defining a function within a loop? In fact there doesn't seem to be any reason to have a function at all; just put the code in the loop itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong! The correct indentation is give below, there has to be 4 space indent

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def Upload(request):
    for count, x in enumerate(request.FILES.getlist("files")):
        def process(f):
            with open('/Users/Michel/django_1.8/projects/upload/media/file_' + str(count), 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in f.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
        process(x)
    return HttpResponse("File(s) uploaded!")
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed that error but now it has returned me to the original error that I was having, the server is telling me: 
Using the URLconf defined in upload.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^index/
even though i set up the whole database exactly according to the tutorial

Comment: accept thne answer if it helped you to solve the issue! Thanks

Comment: The indentation in the question was wrong, but Python does not require 4-space indentation. It just needs to be consistent.