# How to interpret python code in Django when trying to open files?

Tags: python, django

I have below codes written in python in Django. Since I am new to Django and python, I have a hard time understanding below code. What makes me understand hard is that the function `process(f)` inside in the for-loop. why does it have to be inside the for-loop?

```
def Upload(request):
    for count,x in enumerate(request.FILES.getlist("files")):
        def process(f):
            with open('/Users/sclee/PycharmProjects/uploadFile/bin/upload/media/file_' + str(count),'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in f.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
        process(x)
    return HttpResponse("File(s) uploaded")
```

Comment: It doesn't. This is silly code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to. You can put it anywhere, even outside of the python file in which you are uploading files. Lets say, you have it `handle_upload.py` file, in which you have written `process` function to handle uploads. Then you can use it like this:

```
# in handle_upload.py

def process(f, count):
        with open('/Users/sclee/PycharmProjects/uploadFile/bin/upload/media/file_' + str(count)+'.txt','wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)


# inside views.py

from .handle_upload import process  # assuming handle_upload.py is in same directroy as this view file

def Upload(request):  # use snake_case for defining functions. Please read PEP-8 Style guide
    for count,x in enumerate(request.FILES.getlist("files")):
        process(x, count)
    return HttpResponse("File(s) uploaded")
```

Comment: Though wouldn't this miss the file name str(count)?
Define it elsewhere but the define line should be:
process(count,f)
And when calling the function it should be process(count,x)

Comment: I think this misses the point that this extra function is completely useless if not confusing. There's no need for it.

Comment: @gregory that depends on the use-case. There might be a reason for coming back to this function in the future, in which case moving it out and declaring it as a function is useful. 
However like you say, declaring it inside the for-loop is entirely pointless if that's the only place it is used.

Comment: @ScottEvans, OP is confused about this function inside a function. And, he should be! As defined, it is useless. Giving him the impression in an answer that it is normal or that it should be done (because of some rare corner case) is misleading. Besides, I've seen this question asked before and believe it is just copy/paste coding, not some cleverness; e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369180/django-upload-files-proving-more-difficult-than-necessary